# Is it possible to resize an embedded Yammer comments web part after all the comments are loaded?

Tags: cross-domain, yammer, iframe-resizer

I have added the yammer comments embed code to our SharePoint 2013 page layout. We would like the height of the feed to change depending on how many comments there are.

I tried using the yam.on code mentioned here:
https://developer.yammer.com/docs/feed-events

But the /embed/feed/loadingCompleted event seems to trigger before the comments have finished rendering. Is there any kind of postMessage that I can use to know when the content has completely finished loading? Ideally it would pass the contents height to the parent window.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to ask Yammer to add support.